# AngularJS - Why is ng-mouseleave not woking properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm posting my code, because for the sake of me, I can't figure out why ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave are not working properly... They fire correctly only when the mouse enters and leaves from the side(left/right) and with the mouseleave still sometimes it doesn't fire up.. I can't use css to apply the needed classes, because I have to watch for a ctrl key press event, so I have to stick to the ng-mouseenter/leave. I tried also with ng-mouseover/out - they're almost not working at all. Any idea why that is and how to fix it? I would be very thankful.

view.html

```
<div ng-controller="ControlCenterViewController as controlCenter">
   <div class="controlcenter" ng-repeat="cat in controlCenter.categories">
      <div class="controlcenter-category">{{cat.title}}</div>

      <div class="controlcenter-shortcut" ng-repeat="shortcut in cat.exts"
            ng-click="controlCenter.onSelect(shortcut, $event)" ng-class="class" 
           ng-mouseenter="controlCenter.hoverIn($event, shortcut)" ng-mouseleave="controlCenter.hoverOut($event, shortcut)">
                  <span class="shortcut-remove hidden-shortcut">
                  <clr-icon shape="times-circle" class="is-error" size="12"></clr-icon>
                  </span>
                  <span class="{{shortcut.icon}} controlcenter-shortcut-icon-display" ng-if="controlCenter.hasClass(shortcut)"></span>
                  <img class="controlcenter-shortcut-icon" ng-src="{{shortcut.icon}}" ng-if="!controlCenter.hasClass(shortcut)"/>
               <div data-test-id="{{shortcut.targetViewUid}}" class="controlcenter-shortcut-label">{{shortcut.name}}</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
    function hoverIn(event, shortcut){
        if(perspectivesService.isEditEnabled()){
            console.log('hover in fired');
            var target = angular.element(event.target).find('span.shortcut-remove');
            if(event.ctrlKey){
                target.removeClass('hidden-shortcut');
                target.addClass('current-shortcut');
            }
        }
    }

    function hoverOut(event, shortcut){
        if(perspectivesService.isEditEnabled()){
            console.log('hover out fired');
            var target = angular.element(event.target).find('span.shortcut-remove');
                target.removeClass('current-shortcut');
                target.addClass('hidden-shortcut');
        }
    }
```

css

```
.hidden-shortcut {
   display: none;
}

.current-shortcut {
   display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: could you make you code runnable using jsfiddle or plunkr ??

Comment: addClass, removeClass ay is anti-pattern, it's jQuery way. Better have ng-show or ng-if on that span element & change its visibility. Just toggle the flag inside that mouseenter or mouseleave functions. Also, you've to check what perspectivesService.isEditEnabled() is returning.

Answer (score 2):

When I used JQuery in Angularjs, there were several problems.

I've seen so many seniors recommended `Do not use JQuery with Angularjs`,

so I'll suggest one.

I hope this can help you. :)

Check this fiddle.

[Change color of div](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/kx5zr7k3/)

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope){
    $scope.colorClass = 'red-div';
    $scope.changeClass = function (css) {
        $scope.colorClass = css;
    };
});
```

Maybe this is not same as your purpose.

But if you want more information, please give me some feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery with Angularjs but you have to set the jQuery's $ symbol as as jQuery.